# Laravel function name must be a string

Tags: php, function, laravel

Laravel

What mistake am I actually doing?

Please have a look at the image below:
http://1drv.ms/1ybX4Cg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your code and errors in the post.

Comment: I've posted the error in the linked image and the code and error is in there.

Comment: Yes but the image may be gone tomorrow, and the whole thread would be useless then. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

I think

```
$body['user_id'] = $user()->id;
```

should be

```
$body['user_id'] = $user->id;
```

Comment: Just got it correct. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I don't think it's wise to answer such a poor question that doesn't follow the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). By answering you encourage the OP and other users to keep asking questions of poor quality...